# How can I get these values and text strings added in during my for/next loop?

Tags: vba

I have a series of numbers that get updated to a master sheet based on their own separate tabs. I enter a set of numbers in `rngB` and they populate based on the dimensions of the for/next loop based on the multipliers in the array `multplr`.

Everything works as it should, but I'm trying to also have a range `(x,40)` populate with this: `wsA.Cells(x, 40).Formula = "=""TSR: ""&AX6&"" - ""&AY6&"" - ""&AZ6&"" USD Annual"`

Loop:

```
        For x = 6 To FinalRow
            wsA.Cells(x, 40).Formula = "=""TSR: ""&AX6&"" - ""&AY6&"" - ""&AZ6&"" USD Annual"
        Next x
```

it populates the formula, but doesn't autofill like it should, it just repeats the save thing in `Cells(6,40)`

I know there's the autofill/destination method, but my prior for/next formula loop works as it should, so I'm confused what's going on here.

Rest of script:

```
Sub UpdateTSRS()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wsA As Worksheet, wsB As Worksheet
Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range, rngC As Range
Dim rIterator As Range, c As Range, spread As Range
Dim fndRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, x As Long
Dim multplr As Variant
Dim FinalRow
multplr = Array(1, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.3)

Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
Set wsA = wbk.Sheets("Annual")
Set wsB = wbk.Sheets("New Annual")
Set rngA = wsA.Range(wsA.Range("E6"), wsA.Range("E6").End(xlDown))
Set rngB = wsB.Range(wsB.Range("A2"), wsB.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set rngC = wsA.Range(wsA.Range("AW6"), wsA.Range("AW6").End(xlDown))

FinalRow = wsA.Cells(Rows.Count, 49).End(xlUp).Row

For Each rIterator In rngB
        On Error Resume Next
        fndRow = Application.Match(rIterator.Value, rngA, 0) + _
            rngA.Range("E1").Row - 1
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Else
        For i = 0 To 4
            For j = 3 To 9
                If j <> 6 Then
                Set c = wsA.Cells(fndRow + i, j + 43)
                c.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(255, 255, 0)
                wsA.Cells(fndRow + i, j + 43).Value = rIterator.Offset(, j - 1).Value * multplr(i)
            End If
            Next j
        Next i
        End If
        Err.Clear
    Next rIterator



        For x = 6 To FinalRow
            wsA.Cells(x, 49).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[-3]"
        Next x

        For x = 6 To FinalRow
            wsA.Cells(x, 40).Formula = "=""TSR: ""&AX6&"" - ""&AY6&"" - ""&AZ6&"" USD Annual"
        Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you should edit your question to clarify what you mean by '..but doesn't autofill like it should...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have told the formula to use AX6, AY6 and AZ6 so it will put this on every row.  You should change this to

```
wsA.Cells(x, 40).Formula = "=""TSR: ""&AX" & x & "&"" - ""&AY" & x & "&"" - ""&AZ" & x & "&"" USD Annual"""
```

or slightly easier to read

```
wsA.Cells(x, 40).FormulaR1C1 ="TSR: "&RC[49]&" - "&RC[50]&" - "&RC[51]&" USD Annual"
```

Answer (score 1):

No loop needed:

```
wsA.Range(wsA.Cells(6, 40),wsA.Cells(FinalRow, 40)).Formula = "=""TSR: ""&AX6&"" - ""&AY6&"" - ""&AZ6&"" USD Annual"
```

Same with other formula:

```
wsA.Range(wsA.Cells(6, 49),wsA.Cells(FinalRow, 49)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]-RC[-3]"
```

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted, but I want to say thanks. I wish this was like reddit where you can comment `Solution Verified` in order to credit multiple answers.